# I am testing my android application on my phone,and i want to access my camera and see the logs as well

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-camera, android-testing

I am testing my android application on my phone.Since my phone is connected to my PC with a USB cable,its not allowing me to access the camera. And i need to see the logs on eclipse.Is there any way,so that i can see the logs and test my application where i need to access my phone camera?

Comment: yes,i want to see logCat,because my application is crashing after clicking the photo and saving it in gallery. It is not going to the next page,but it is working fine on emulator.

Comment: does your device show up in eclipse when u debug or run your app?

Comment: yes my device is visible in eclipse

Comment: in my experience with eclipse, the logcat is sometimes buggy. A simple eclipse restart fixes it. I prefer Android Studios Logcat

Comment: am getting open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: i expect you have not added permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Logcat is always available. And if you are opening Camera from your app then you can see Logcat messages

> so may be there are few reason as follows :-

1. check if connect your device as usb debug mode.
2. your device should not be connect as a media device.
   hope it will solve this issue

Comment: am getting open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

Comment: what you are trying to open?

Answer (score 0):

Which os used in your pc.

1. if you use mac os then goto-->DDMS(eclipse)--> select your device then you will able to see your log cat.
2. if you use Ubuntu then you will mention device id in some file in your pc.
   [check link.](http://dimitar.me/how-to-connect-your-android-phone-to-ubuntu-to-do-developmenttestinginstallations-or-tethering/)
3. if you use window-7 then i can not not help you... because i am suffering this issue. :(